# Flutter align IconButton content to parent boundaries

Tags: flutter, widget, alignment, iconbutton

Is it possible to get IconButton content (icon) aligned to parent widget boundary?

Got code like this

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                splashRadius: 20,
                constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/arrow_left.svg', color: primaryColor)
            )
          ],
        )
    );
```

I want to keep Icon aligned to a Row widget left boundary and keep on-click splash animation around that positioning.

With this parameter it is possible to position Icon to the place where I need it, but on-click splash animation remains unaligned.

```
alignment: Alignment.centerLeft
```

So it does something like this (vertical markup line is parent widget boundary)

[image]

But I need this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is something to be done with the resource than the code.

```
       Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, size: 20),
                      splashRadius: 20,
                      onPressed: () => {},
                    ),
                  ],
                )
            )
```

I used your code, added size to it, and used the inbuilt resource.

```
icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, size: 20),
```

The output is

[image]

Comment: This is not what i meant in my question, if you try to align this by parent boundary you will get same result as i did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in simple way like below.

```
     Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/arrow_left.svg',
                        color: primaryColor)),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ))
```

Comment: IconButton content remains unaligned to Row's boundaries, it still has that padding.